# Looping all files in a folder fails after first iteration

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop a macro through all files in a folder. After the first iteration, I get the error "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument". What could be causing this? The folder contains a lot of xlsx and csv files. The macro is set to run on the xlsx files only.

```
Sub Step18LoopAllFilesInAFolder()

    folderName = "D:\Users\Desktop\Macro Data\Test"
    If Right(folderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then folderName = folderName & Application.PathSeparator
    Fname = Dir(folderName & "*.xlsx")

    'loop through the files
    Do While Len(Fname)

        With Workbooks.Open(folderName & Fname)

           Call Step17MasterMacro


        End With

        ' go to the next file in the folder
        Fname = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `Step17MasterMacro` also using a `Dir` somewhere? if so, you will run into problems like this. You cannot next the `Dir` functions. It would be better to use a `FileSystemObject` or build an `Array` out of the parent `Dir` function first.

Comment: @braX no. This is the only DIR in the workbook

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: @BigBen `Fname = Dir`

Comment: @braX, actually, there might a be a DIR within the code. Reviewing it now... thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @braX's suggestion, I changed to the following. Works like a charm!

```
Sub Step18LoopAllFilesInAFolder()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim wb As Object

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    folderPath = "D:\Users\Desktop\Macro Data\Test"
    Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)


    For Each wb In folder.Files
        If Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Then
            Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
            Call Step17MasterMacro
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks much better. And since you technically learned something and answered your own question by writing the code yourself based on a suggestion, you can vote your answer as the accepted answer to your question.